# How do I break from the main/outer loop in a double/nested loop?

Tags: java, loops, syntax, for-loop, break

If I have loop in a loop and once an `if` statement is satisfied I want to break main loop, how am I supposed to do that?

This is my code:

```
for (int d = 0; d < amountOfNeighbors; d++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < myArray.size(); c++) {
        if (graph.isEdge(listOfNeighbors.get(d), c)) {
            if (keyFromValue(c).equals(goalWord)) { // Once this is true I want to break main loop.
                System.out.println("We got to GOAL! It is "+ keyFromValue(c));
                break; // This breaks the second loop, not the main one.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a label. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Using a labeled break:

```
mainloop:
for(){
 for(){
   if (some condition){
     break mainloop;
   }
  }
}
```

---

**Also See**

- *[“loop:” in Java code. What is this, and why does it compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821827/loop-in-java-code-what-is-this-why-does-it-compile-and-generally-wtf/3821841#3821841)*
- [Documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.7)

Comment: Awesome! I learnt something new. I thought labels were for days gone by (remember GW-BASIC?). I would have used boolean flags for this, but labels are much cooler!

Comment: @ADTC GW-BASIC never supported textual labels, only numerical line numbers (and it required those). IIRC, coming out of Microsoft it was QuickBASIC that added support for textual labels, as well as named subroutines. QBasic certainly included such support if Wikipedia is to be trusted, at least no later than Visual Basic.

Answer (score 28):

You can add labels to your loop, and use that `labelled break` to break out of the appropriate loop: -

```
outer: for (...) {
    inner: for(...) {
        if (someCondition) {
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

See these links for more information:

- *[Branching Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)*
- [JLS - Break Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)

Answer (score 12):

You can just `return` the control from that function. Or use the ugly `break labels` approach :)

If there is another code parts after your `for` statement, you can refactor the loops in a function.

IMO, the use of breaks and continue should be discouraged in OOP, since they affect the readability and the maintenance. Sure, there are cases where they are handy, but in general I think that we should avoid them, since they will encourage the use of goto style programing.

Apparently variations to this questions are posted a lot. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11133277/1613867) Peter provided some good and odd uses using labels.

Comment: Source/defend your claim that labels are ugly

Comment: In this particular case, return may be appropriate. However labels are not ugly and often useful.

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks, ugly and hard to debug.

Comment: I disagree. They are not harder to debug and shouldn't be hard to understand either. I don't consider them ugly at all.

Comment: @JanDvorak I agree, probably hard was too strong :). I was trying to say that it's easier to read a code without goto logic.

Comment: (I generally find some languages unbearably hard to read for other reasons - I can't even recall the last time I used explicit "double loops" that required breaking in a language that had proper HoF support and a supportive collection APIs. This would be much more cleanly written in terms of an "Any" function, IMOHO ;-)

Comment: @pst I agree. Using a function will help him properly maintain and reuse the code, at least.

Comment: IMO, it's good to rethink about how to write the code again to avoid labled loops. The reason why so many people don't know that they exist is because we don't need them. I am not saying they are always bad.

Comment: @BheshGurung That was what I was trying to suggest with my answer too, but it seems that many are still used to the goto logic :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like for Java a labeled break appears to be the way to go (based on the consensus of the other answers).

But for many (most?) other languages, or if you want to avoid any `goto` like control flow, you need to set a flag:

```
bool breakMainLoop = false;
for(){
    for(){
        if (some condition){
            breakMainLoop = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (breakMainLoop) break;
}
```

Comment: If a labelled break really is the way to go in Java, then the way to go in C/C++ is a goto.

Comment: Also, the question is clearly labelled as `java`.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that someone searching for 'break nested loop' might come upon it.  @EvanHarper I would agree with that line of reasoning, but I haven't spent much time in Java so just went with the consensus of the other answers...

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
for(int d = 0; d < amountOfNeighbors; d++){
    for(int c = 0; c < myArray.size(); c++){
        ...
            d = amountOfNeighbors;
            break;
        ...
    }
    // No code here
}
```

Comment on `break label` : it's a forward goto. It can break any statement and jump to the next:

```
foo: // Label the next statement (the block)
{
    code ...
    break foo;  // goto [1]
    code ...
}

//[1]
```

Comment: Syntax error. Missing a semicolon.

Comment: haha :) Will sure upvote for this creative thinking

Comment: I hope noone ever uses this in production :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best and easy methods for beginners even:

```
outerloop:

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){

    // Here we can break the outer loop by:
    break outerloop;

    innerloop:

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){

        // Here we can break innerloop by:
        break innerloop;
    }
}
```